# I am getting a TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object when using Object.assign

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There probably better way of doing this, but before that I just wan't to know why is this throwing an error. Is it the `setState()` that is causing the problem?

```
onSubmit = async (dispatch, e) => {
e.preventDefault();

const { name, email, phone } = this.state;
```

Right here is the problem, but I do not understand why.

> ```
> // Check For Errors
> if (name === '' || email === '' || phone === '') {
>   let errObject = Object.assign(
>     name === '' ? { name: 'Name is required' } : null,
>     email === '' ? { email: 'Email is required' } : null,
>     phone === '' ? { phone: 'Phone is required' } : null
>   );
>   this.setState({
>     errors: {
>       ...this.state.errors,
>       ...errObject
>     }
>   });
>
>   return;
> }
> ```

```
const updContact = {
  name,
  email,
  phone
};

const { id } = this.props.match.params;

const res = await axios.put(
  `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`,
  updContact
);

dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_CONTACT', payload: res.data });

// Clear State
this.setState({
  name: '',
  email: '',
  phone: '',
  errors: {}
});

this.props.history.push('/');
};
```

Comment: What is the initial value of name, email and phone that is in constructor?

Comment: Their initial values are empty strings.

Comment: Try not to use logic inside Object.assign, and also check official documentation for this method at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because Object.assign is being called on null. You should assign an empty object in your else condition:

```
let errObject = Object.assign(
    name === '' ? { name: 'Name is required' } : {},
    email === '' ? { email: 'Email is required' } : {},
    phone === '' ? { phone: 'Phone is required' } : {}
  );
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. It is no longer throwing an error. But I have a new problem. How do I filter out the name, email, or phone in the state.error if they are not empty on submit?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get you. Can you please rephrase what you want to say?

Comment: The errors are conditionally rendered bellow the input field. The problem is, I want the state.errors.name to no longer show if the user types something in the input and submit the form. Maybe remove the items in the error state.